# How to check the brackets in console....?

Tags: console, scheme, brackets

When I type scheme programming in console, there are many brackets and I am not sure which one is opened, which one is closed.

So, is there any command/hot key to check the corresponding brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what Scheme interpreter are you using?. I advise you to use an IDE instead of using the console, for instance [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) is very user-friendly and you'll never have trouble finding your brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Run your scheme interpreter with `rlwrap` if you have it installed, which will provide paren-matching.

For example, I am using the Chicken Scheme interpreter `csi` that does not provide read-line functionality. I can run `rlwrap csi` and I will get paren-matching, history, and more.